# airflow experimental api dagrun give 400 error: what should be the input parameter

Tags: airflow

A POST request from postman to 
http://host:8080/api/experimental/dags/test_flow/dag_runs gives 
"400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." 
when it try to get_json from from request. ie at line data = request.get_json(force=True)

What should be the inputs to this API call ..?

Comment: This looks like a malformed json sent with the POST request. You should post the json you sent to get help on this.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm seeing the same issue and I'm not passing anything in the POST body as it's not required according to these docs: https://airflow.apache.org/api.html. Simply POSTing the the `/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs` url.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue, solved it by POSTing an empty JSON

```
curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your postman request should be sent like this.

-H flag means headers and -d flag means data in a POST request

[image: Headers]

[image: Data]